# Redis Expiry Key Event generates twice for same key

Tags: key, spring-data-redis

Hi Im new to redis expiry key events.

In local notifications are generated once only for different keys expiration.

I have 3 keys to expire at different time.

But problem is Message Listener gets two times same event for same key in production.

On locally it is generated only one time.

Please help me.

I have try this code

```
@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            String key = new String(message.getBody());
```

```
@Bean
   RedisMessageListenerContainer keyExpirationListenerContainer(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ExpirationListener expirationListener) {
       RedisMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
       listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
       listenerContainer.addMessageListener(expirationListener, new PatternTopic("__keyevent@*__:expired"));
       listenerContainer.setErrorHandler(e -> logger.error("There was an error in redis key expiration listener container", e));
       return listenerContainer;
   }
```

Comment: Hello, can you share what your keyspace notifications settings are in Redis?  You should be able to get this using `config get notify-keyspace-events` in the CLI.  Also if you're looking for more information on keyspace events, here's a demo repo that has a video associated with it https://github.com/redis-developer/keyspace-notifications-node-redis